# hyperledger composer error when using TLS

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have succeeded in building the `Hyperledger Composer` with 2 peers, and peers are deployed on a different server. The whole Hyperledger Fabric Network worked very well without using TLS.

BUT when I try to use TLS, the chain code docker container(like `dev-peer0-org10-test-com-blah-0.1.0`) exited, and I use docker logs, it tells me :

```
hyperledger x509: a certificate signed by an unknown authority
```

[image1: docker logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35fSy.png)

I find that env variable `CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE` in chain-code docker container(like `dev-peer0-org10-test-com-blah-0.1.0`) is empty, and the `CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED` is `true`. I think this is the reason, but I can not fix it.
What should I do if I want to use TLS?

[image2: build docker container without CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e08zd.png)

Comment: only with deploy with composer-playground. composer network deploy works very well !!

Answer (score 0):

Having setup/configured your MSP environment and used best practises -> http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html and TLS enabled using the proper signer certificates, you can take it forward to try out Hyperledger Composer.

Then you can (obviously once you've set up Composer as you have done and deployed your business network(s) etc etc.  You can configure your Composer v1 HLF connection profile to connect via TLS (grpcs) to the running Hyperledger Fabric runtime environment - see this Bluemix connection profile example below (it has the certificate files and X590 entries pasted in the example):

```
{
    "type": "hlf",
    "membershipServicesURL": "grpcs://f8946a6180f2431088ca17ce931a49dc-ca.us.org.acme.com:30001",
    "peerURL": "grpcs://f8946a6180f2431088ca17ce931a49dc-vp1.us.acme.com:30001",
    "eventHubURL": "grpcs://f8946a6180f2431088ca17ce931a49dc-vp1.us.acme.com:31001",
    "keyValStore": "/home/composer/.composer-credentials",
    "deployWaitTime": 300,
    "invokeWaitTime": 30,
    "certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIID6TCCA26gAwIBAgIQCiYEWw1faoRpM2xufaiPLTAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjBMMQsw\nCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMSYwJAYDVQQDEx1EaWdp\nQ2VydCBFQ0MgU2VjdXJlIFNlcnZlciBDQTAeFw0xNjA2MDcwMDAwMDBaFw0xOTA2\nMTIxMjAwMDBaMIGJMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzERMA8GA1UECBMITmV3IFlvcmsxDzAN\nBgNVBAcTBkFybW9uazE0MDIGA1UEChMrSW50ZXJuYXRpb25hbCBCdXNpbmVzcyBN\nYWNoaW5lcyBDb3Jwb3JhdGlvbjEgMB4GA1UEAwwXKi51cy5ibG9ja2NoYWluLmli\nbS5jb20wWTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAARTKAZypDOqw34HWujQeL82\nj1e9rN1inpN6ngrq49+OpYIe8ckHnJhsWPpf+zeIQePboDQVUTDtYXh7212BsVoX\no4IB8jCCAe4wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUo53mH/naOU/AbuiRy5Wl2jHiCp8wHQYDVR0O\nBBYEFK+1RoBnUnb8nr2hNtkUu3FRrbYuMDkGA1UdEQQyMDCCFyoudXMuYmxvY2tj\naGFpbi5pYm0uY29tghV1cy5ibG9ja2NoYWluLmlibS5jb20wDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQD\nAgeAMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjBpBgNVHR8EYjBgMC6g\nLKAqhihodHRwOi8vY3JsMy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vc3NjYS1lY2MtZzEuY3JsMC6g\nLKAqhihodHRwOi8vY3JsNC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vc3NjYS1lY2MtZzEuY3JsMEwG\nA1UdIARFMEMwNwYJYIZIAYb9bAEBMCowKAYIKwYBBQUHAgEWHGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3\nLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9DUFMwCAYGZ4EMAQICMHsGCCsGAQUFBwEBBG8wbTAkBggr\nBgEFBQcwAYYYaHR0cDovL29jc3AuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMEUGCCsGAQUFBzAChjlo\ndHRwOi8vY2FjZXJ0cy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vRGlnaUNlcnRFQ0NTZWN1cmVTZXJ2\nZXJDQS5jcnQwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADAKBggqhkjOPQQDAgNpADBmAjEA7LViaN74\nOwIp/zqfwSRvURg965+m73/edCeNKrsLf6GuE0sLwpX6pQNnDlr6SzGnAjEA+qk0\nsYRnd2gCQeD9fWbCJIw0vJDqeZr1WJ64aVoJ8kyASzY/yoarSm2wqujXJwEf\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nEa8/B6hPatJ0ES8q/HO3X8IVQwVs1n3aAr0im0/T+Xc=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nCAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAESrciIxpg0X40KPMbp1ZWVbd4=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
    "certificatePath": "/certs/peer/cert.pem"
}
```

membershipServicesURL is always "grpcs://" + url from the "ca" object (url also being discovery_host + ":" + discovery_port).

peerURL is always "grpcs://" + discovery_host + ":" + discovery_port from one of the peers listed in the "peers" array.

eventHubURL is always "grpcs://" + event_host + ":" + event_port from one of the peers listed in the "peers" array.

keyValStore is a directory on the file system of the system running Composer. If using the Docker images, then use the "/home/composer/.composer-credentials" path, otherwise use a directory that exists on your machine.

As for globals usage - we have a sample TLS Docker yaml file that may be of useful reference.

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-systests/hlfv1/docker-compose.tls.yml

Comment: Thank you, when I use this command : "composer network deploy" to deploy .bna file on fabric, it works well. So  I think  connection profile and the certs is OK. This problem only happens on using "composer-playground".  We are using test servers, "composer-playground" is very convenient to deploy the .bna file. 

Should i give up using the "composer-playground"?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues, however we are using composer v0.7.5 and fabric v1.0 alpha. Two things we've changed and solved our problem:
1. We had to use /.hfc-key-store in composer playground (a limitiation coming from HFC/SDK, not composer itself)
2. We had to put TLS certificate into a connection profile manually (and don't forget the closing \n at the end). Import the certificate from the UI didn't work.